# weird jquery value selection

Tags: jquery, python, html, list

Ok so let's say I have two  elements built like this:

```
<div id="A_list_div" class="link_list">     
            <ul id="A_list">
                {% for item in order %}
                {% if A[item] == 'checked' %}
                <li class="list_item_click_shift"><label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="{{item}}" checked=""/>{{item}}</label></li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="list_item_click_shift"><label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="{{item}}"/>{{item}}</label></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>               
        </div>
        <div id="B_list_div" class="link_list">
            <ul id="B_list">
                <li class="list_item_click_shift" id="A_clear_li"><label>Clear or Select All<input type="checkbox" name="A_clear" checked=""/></label></li>
                {% for item in B %}
                <li class="list_item_click_shift"><label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="{{item}}" checked=""/>{{item}}</label></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The stuff in the {% %} is just flask related code, all it does is populate the list elements from the server. List A is build first from a GET, the user selects an item and it appears in the B List. I wrote some jquery that is suppose to do a few things:

1. If the system GETS items to the B list they all appear checked and if they are in the A list they are checked there as well.
2. if an item is represented in both list and the user toggles either, the toggle effect should be on both, and obviously if it is only in one list it should just toggle the check mark in itself.
3. Clear or Select All item will toggle all the items in list B and their counter-parts if they appear in list A.

So far I have this is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=A]").change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name=B][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[name=B][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $("input[name=B]").change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name=A][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[name=A][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $("input[name=A_clear]").change(function(){
       if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
       {
           $("input[name=B]").each(function(){
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
              $('input[name=A][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', false);
           });
       }
       else
       {
           $("input[name=B]").each(function(){
               $(this).prop('checked', true);
               $('input[name=A][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
           });
       } 
    });
});
```

Ok so this works, surprisingly since I only have a few hours of jquery exposure, however I noticed that this comes to a halt when one of the values from the  has a set of double quotes in it, like vdd"f"dfds, it either cannot find it's equivalent in the other list and if I hit the toggle all button it will stop once it hits that value, anyone have a way to make it just accept and use the value in the value attribute even if it has double quotes like that or another way to do all of this? Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]
```

Having a double quote in your value will close the value tag.

You will need to escape them:

```
 str = $(this).val().replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
 $('input[name=A][value="' + str+ '"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, while I have you do you have any idea why the "input[name=A_clear]" function is not clearing the associated "input[name=A]" when it is clearing the B?  Odd since it is essentially the same code in the "input[name=B]" function which does clear the associated A.

Comment: It does seem to clear it for me, http://fiddle.jshell.net/rs79up0k/, or am I understanding you wrong? I click the first clear all button, it checks the checkboxes and when I click again, it clears them both, the second clear button only clears the fisrt two checkboxes.

Comment: It works, I had added your adjustment too high up in the script. Directly under `$("input[name=A_clear]").change(function(){` which was giving me the value of the all clear/select checkbox, not helpful, instead of under each `$(this).prop('checked', false);` line, ty again.